# Provable formulas in everyday Mathematics

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory

Basically all statements ( lemmas, theoremas, corollaries ) in Mathematics can be expressed as a conditional statement in first-order language, or existential statement ( existence proofs ).   Here i'm interested in the conditional statements case.

Every theorem mostly has assumptions $A_1, A_2,.., A_n$ and a conclusion $C$ ( even if it involves a bi-conditional, we can split into two cases ) . We can join all assumptions into one single formula $A =  A_1 \land A_2 \land ... \land A_n$, and simply consider a theorem as a conditional statement $A \rightarrow C$.

To have a proof of the theorem represented by $A \rightarrow C$ is to be able to deduce $C$ from $A$, that is, obtain a finite list whose elements are either $A_1, A_2,.., A_n$,  a tautology in first order language ( an axiom ) or some formula obtained by applying some rule of inference from two preceding formulas in the list ; the last element in the finite list is $C$.

Now, we learn that first order logic is sound and semantically complete, so we can conclude that every provable formula ( theorem ) is a tautology in first order language, and at the same time we learn ( by Deduction Theorem ) that if $C$ was deduced from $A$, then $A \rightarrow C$ is provable ( we were proving $A \rightarrow C$ is a tautology in first place).

While i understand that $A \rightarrow C$ must be a tautology, when we say every theorem ( from any branch of mathematics, number theory, abstract algebra, real analysis,etc ) we prove is simply a conditional formula $A \rightarrow C$ that is provable, are we saying it's provable from which set of axioms ?

Since the idea of a formula being provable, requires some set of axioms which the formula can be proved from,  how do we understand that every tautology in first order logic is provable ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Basically all statements ( lemmas, theoremas, corollaries ) in Mathematics can be expressed as a conditional statement in first-order language."  They can?  Not even every contingent proposition in logic can get expressed as a conditional.  So what makes you think all statements in Mathematics can get expressed in terms of a conditional?  Also, last I checked "there exists a prime greater than 4" is a mathematical statement.  How do you express that as a conditional?

Comment: True, added that on the list.But i'm interested mainly on the conditional statement's case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you have made a little mistake; we need some precise definitions.

Consider *first-order* logic and a "standard" *proof system* for it; i.e.logical axioms + inference rules (a so-called *Hilbert-style* proof system; see Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584888768) (4ed - 1997) or Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd - 2001); for *natural deduction*, thinghs are a little bit different [more rules, no logical axioms], but the basic concepts are the same; see Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447145577) (5th ed - 2013) or Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199215626) (2007)).

*Note*. Mendelson uses two inference rules : *modus ponens* and *geenralization*, while Enderton uses only *modus ponens*.

We have to start from the definition of *deduction* form *assumptions* [see Enderton, page 111] :

> A deduction of $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$ is a finite sequence $(\alpha_0, ... \alpha_n)$ of formulas such that $\alpha_n$ is $\varphi$ and for each $k \le n$, either
>
> ($a_1$) $\alpha_k$ is in $\Gamma$, or
>
> ($a_2$) $\alpha_k$ is in the set $\Lambda$ of *logical axioms*, or
>
> ($b$) $\alpha_k$ is obtained by *modus ponens* from two earlier formulas in the sequence; that is, for some $i$ and $j$ less than $k$, $\alpha_j$ is $\alpha_i \rightarrow \alpha_k$.
>
> If such a deduction exists, we say that $\varphi$ is deducible from $\Gamma$, or that $\varphi$ is a theorem of $\Gamma$, and we write $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

Consider now, your example : "a proof of the theorem represented by $A \rightarrow C$ is to be able to deduce $C$ from $A$".

In this way, we obtain a deduction of $C$ from the *assumption* $A$ :

> $A \vdash C$.

Of course, in the above deduction, we have used also the set $\Lambda$ of (logical) axioms.

Then we apply *Deduction Theorem* to get :

> that if $C$ was deduced from $A$, then $A \rightarrow C$ is provable, i.e. $\vdash A \rightarrow C$.

By *soundness*, we conclude that $A \rightarrow C$ is a (first-order) *valid*.

See this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759804/model-theory-and-proof-theory-in-propositional-logic) for more details.

Consider now a *finite* set of *sentences* $\Gamma = \{ \gamma_1,... , \gamma_n \}$. Then, as you said :

> we can join all assumptions into one single formula $G = \gamma_1 \land \gamma_2 \land ... \land \gamma_n$, and simply consider a theorem as a conditional statement $G \rightarrow \varphi$.

For example, consider *Group theory* [see Mendelson, page 71].

$G$ is the *conjunction* of the (finite) list of first-order axiom of *group theory*.

Now, let $\varphi$ be a theorem whatever of *group theory*; from the consideartions above, we have :

> $G \vdash \varphi$,

from which we conclude :

> $\vdash G \rightarrow \varphi$.

The last one is a *valid* formula of first-order logic; that is it is *true* in every interpretation. This is consistent with mathematical practice: if we consider a structure that is a *group*, this will obviously satisfy *group axioms*, i.e. $G$.

Being $\varphi$ a *tehorem* of group theory, by *soundness* it will be a *logical consequence* of $G$, i.e. it will be true in every interpretation that satisfy $G$. In conclusion, $G \rightarrow \varphi$ will be true in every interpreattion, i.e.*valid*.

But this does not imply that $\varphi$ is *valid*, because it is **not** a theorem of first-order logic.

In conclusion,

> > $G \rightarrow \varphi$ is a logical *theorem* (of f-o logic) and thus it is *valid*.

Instead :

> > $\varphi$ is a *theorem* of *group theory* but not necessarily a logical one; thus, it is **not** *valid*.

*Added - April,23*

Consider Enderton's system (I use it for simplicity, because it has *modus ponens* as single rule of inference).

The axiom system for f-o logic [see page 112] is :

> The logical axioms are then all *generalizations* of wffs of the following forms, where $x$ and $у$ are variables and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are wffs:
>
> 1. Tautologies;
> 2. $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha(t/x)$, where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$;
> 3. $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow (\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta)$;
> 4. $\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \alpha$, where $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

In addition, the *equality axioms*.

Consider the f-o language for *number theory* [see Enderton, page 70] : an *individual constant* : $0$, the *successor* (unary) function : $S$, the two (binary) functions "sum" : $*$ and "product" : $\times$.

With this language we build the following instance of axiom 2 :

> $\forall x \lnot (S(x) = 0) \rightarrow \lnot (1 = 0)$;

where we have used as $\alpha$ the formula : $\lnot (S(x) = 0)$ and as $t$ the *term* : $S(0)$, i.e.$1$.

Being an instance of a first-order axiom, the formula is *provable* :

> $\vdash \forall x \lnot (S(x) = 0) \rightarrow \lnot (1 = 0)$,

i.e.it is a *theorem* of f-o logic, because we have proved it using (only) f-o logical axioms.

Thus, by *soundness* is *valid* (i.e.true in every interpretation).

Consider now the f-o axiom system for *number theory* [see Enderton, page 203] ; the first one is :

> $\forall x \lnot (S(x) = 0)$.

Thus, from the above instance of f-o axiom 2, we have :

> > $\forall x \lnot (S(x) = 0) \vdash \lnot (1 = 0)$.

In conclusion, $\lnot (1 = 0)$ is a *theorem* of *number theory*, because we have proved it (in f-o logic) from the (mathematical) axioms of f-o *number theory*.

This theorem is **not** valid; it is a *logical consequence* of the mathematical axioms of *number theory*; thus, it will be *true* in every structure which satisfy f-o number-theory axioms.

Comment: But i still have the doubt, if A -> C ( or G -> phi ) is provable ( valid ), what are the axioms where this can be proved from ? I learned that a formula (A -> C) is provable iff it has a formal proof, that is, a finite list whose elements are either the Axioms , or a formula obtained by applying [ ... ] , the last formula of the proof (A -> C ) .. but since (A->C) is provable, what are the axioms where we can prove (A->C) from ?

Comment: @nerdy - you are again mixing the axioms for f-o logic calculus (e.g.$\vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$ and $\vdash \forall x A \rightarrow A(t/x)$) and the axioms of *group theory* ($G$). In order to consider the case $G \rightarrow \varphi$ you have to start with the definition of *derivation* from *assumption* : $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$. 1/2

Comment: The definition is : To have a proof of $\varphi$ from the set $\Gamma$ of assumptions is to be able to obtain a finite list $A_1,A_2,..,A_n$, whose elements are either in $\Gamma$ or *logical axioms* or some formula obtained by applying some rule of inference from two preceding formulas in the list; the last element in the finite list is $\varphi$. 2/2

Comment: The thing is that my book differentiates between a deduction, and a proof. It doesnt say "to have a proof of phi from some set", it simply says "to have a proof of phi" . Meanwhile, he says "to have a deduction of phi from some set of assumptions". But whenever he talks about proof, he talks about it absolutely : To have a proof of phi, is simply saying that phi is provable, we don't need to say from which set of assumptions, because the definition of proof was absolute.

Comment: Now, i'm wondering if the " formal proof" he was talking about was just some special case of a deduction ( in which we consider the assumptions to be fixed, and to be the set of axioms of the formal system we are considering ). Could that be it ?

Comment: @nerdy - tehre is **no** inconsistency. In f-o calculus, we state the more geenral relation of *deduction* of $\varphi$ from the set of *assumptions* $\Gamma$. Then, with the particular case $\Gamma = \emptyset$ we have : $\vdash \varphi$. In this case, we say that the derivation is a *proof* of $\varphi$ and that $\varphi$ is a *theorem* of f-o logic (like : $\vdash \forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha(t/x)$). In *group theory* we need (in addition to logical axioms) the set of *mathematical* axioms for groups. 1/2

Comment: @nerdy -  We use them as the $\Gamma$ above, and the theorems of *group theory* will be sentences $\sigma$ in f-o language such that $\Gamma \vdash \sigma$. And we follows as before : if $G := \gamma_1 \land ... \land \gamma_n$, then from $\Gamma \vdash \sigma$ to $\vdash G \rightarrow \sigma$. This one **is** a theorem of f-o logic. 2/2

Comment: So, every formula C -> A of f.o language ( theorems,corollaries,etc ) that is a tautology in first order-logic , is provable from the axioms of f.o logic ( because we have soundness and completeness in f.o logic ). But at the same time ,  we can say that every conclusion C of theorems that are valid ( provable from axioms of f.o logic ) can be said to be deduced from A. Hence ,if A is some theory T ( whose conjunction of theory axioms is also T ), if T -> C is provable ( from f.o logic ), a theorem of f.o logic, we can say that C is a theorem of the theory T.

Comment: @nerdy - Yes; we need to cook up several result together: if $T \vdash A$, then $\vdash T \rightarrow A$, by *Deduction Theorem*. Then, if $\vdash T \rightarrow A$, then $\vDash T \rightarrow A$ , by *soundness* of the calculus. Then, if $\vDash T \rightarrow A$, then $T \vDash A$, i.e. $A$ is a *logical consequences* of (the axioms of) $T$, i.e. $A$ is *true* in every interpretation of the language that satisfy $T$. If $T$ is (the axioms of) *group theory*, then a logical consequence of $T$ is true in every structure which is a *group*.

Comment: @nerdy - I'll add something to my answer.